# Link a reflection property to a variable

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

Is possible to link a reflection property to a variable? Just for better code.

```
var xxx = results.Where(r => r.GetType().GetProperty(levelName).GetValue(r, null) == node.Name)
```

is possible convert to something like that?

```
var myReflectedProp = r.GetType().GetProperty(levelName).GetValue(r, null);
var myReflectedProp2 = r.GetType().GetProperty(levelName2).GetValue(r, null);
var xxx = results.Where(r => myReflectedProp && r => myReflectedProp2)
```

Cheers

Comment: Its not clear what you trying to do. Can you please explain?

Comment: I'm just try to make code more readable. Actually my LINQ Where is tooooo long and complex to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you just create the expression tree manually.

```
var myReflectedPropParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(YourType));
var myReflectedProp = Expression.Lambda<Func<YourType, bool>>
    (Expression.MakeMemberAccess(myReflectedPropParameter, typeof(YourType).GetProperty(levelName)), myReflectedPropParameter);
var xxx = results.Where(myReflectedProp);
```

Of course, you will need to add a using statement to `System.Linq.Expressions`.

Comment: Error 2:'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Models.Result,bool>>' a 'System.Func<Models.Result,int,bool>'. Obvious I change YourType with myType :)

Comment: @Kaiser69 yes, YourType was only a placeholder. The code is also not tested, but should work, however. What is the error message that you get?

Comment: var xxx = results.Where(myReflectedProp). Getting error above.

Comment: Ah, I thought `results` was an IQueryable as e.g. for database queries. But it seems like it is just an IEnumerable In that case, you can make it work by creating an object query out of it, e.g. using `results.AsQueryable().Where(myReflectedProp)`

Comment: Mmm. I've done others test but it wont work with string comparision. var xxx = results.AsQuerable().Where(r => filenameProp == MYVARIABLE_FILENAME). Incompatible type Linq.Expression and (string) [yes, I've changed <bool> to <string> in your example.

Comment: That's because a string is not convertable to bool and therefore cannot be used like `.Where(r => r.filename)`. Instead, you need to create a binary expression where the left hand is the member access and the right hand is `Expression.Constant(yourFilename)`